# Rails Cancancan define ability on 3 association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

Using Rails 6 and CanCanCan. Here are my models:

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :shop_reviews, dependent: :destroy
end

class ShopReview < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop, counter_cache: true
  belongs_to :user_profile, counter_cache: true
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user_profile, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :shop_reviews, through: :user_profile
end

class UserProfile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :shop_reviews
end
```

ShopReview table:

```
id, shop_id, user_profile_id, review
```

Association:
1. A shop can have many reviews
2. Only one User Profile can have one review on a shop

Abilities I want to define:
1. User Profile can edit, update, destroy his own review of a shop
2. User Profile cannot create a new review if a review of his exist on that shop

What I tried:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :read, :all
    if user.present?
      can [:update, :destroy], ShopReview, user_profile_id: user.user_profile.id
      can :create, ShopReview do
        !ShopReview.exists?(user_profile_id: user.user_profile.id, shop_id: :shop_id)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But I can't seem to pass in the `shop_id` on visiting /shops/11/shop_reviews/new. Here's the log:

```
Started GET "/shops/11/shop_reviews/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-01-04 00:23:10 +0800
Processing by ShopReviewsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"shop_id"=>"11"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  UserProfile Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "user_profiles".* FROM "user_profiles" WHERE "user_profiles"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/ability.rb:9:in `initialize'
  ShopReview Exists? (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "shop_reviews" WHERE "shop_reviews"."user_profile_id" = $1 AND "shop_reviews"."shop_id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["user_profile_id", 8], ["shop_id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/ability.rb:11:in `block in initialize'
  Shop Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "shops"."created_at" DESC LIMIT $2  [["id", 11], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Comment: You're really butting up against the limit of what CanCanCan can really do. The DSL does not really have a concept of defining authorization rules for nested resources or if it does its going to an absolute mess. I would take a look at Pundit which is just OOP and where you can define your policies however you want without jumping through the hoops of a DSL and jamming everything into a single god class.

Answer (score 0):

You should use gem `pundit` to create authorizations in your app. Pundit is easy to scale than gem `cancancan`. Because `pundit` allows your app to create authorization on each model. You can search more about two gems and choose what is most suitable for you.